# How to declare a Custom ContentQueryMain.xsl for a custom CQWP?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

In my CQ webpart definition, if I replace:

```
<xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" />
```

by

```
<xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMainCustom.xsl" />
```

It still uses the ContentQueryMain.xsl file...

Does anybody have an idea of the reason ?

Comment: How can we tell ? maybe you have the logic inside ? so show us the content of xsl files ...

Comment: the problem is not so deep, in fact, it doesn't seem to see my ContentQueryMainCustom.xsl file even if it is present on the server

Comment: chacheing problems - ressetting ? I use to rename with z in front, then even the filesystem has to be shaken ...

Comment: I did it too, doesn't solve anything, the webpart is still calling the "ContentQueryMain" file...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are modifying the [Xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.cmsdataformwebpart.xsl.aspx) property. Try setting the [XslLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xsllink.aspx) property.